# Clojure Matrix equality, Clojure for Machine Learning

Tags: matrix, clojure

I am trying to understand this function:

```
(defn mat-eq
  "Checks if two matrices are equal"
  [A B]
   (and (= (count A) (count B))
        (reduce #(and %1 %2) (map = A B))))
```

"We first compare the row lenghts of the two matrices using the count and = functions, and then use the reduce function to compare the inner vector elements." I dont understand this part: "Essentially, the reduce function repeatedly applies a function that accepts two arguments to consecutive elements in a sequence and returns the final result when all the elements in the sequence have been reduced by the applied function."
 Can somebody explain this part: 
(reduce #(and %1 %2) (map = A B))

Comment: What part of the reduction do you need help with? The description it gives seems pretty clear.

Comment: Can you explain (map = A B)? What does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is capable of taking multiple collections instead of just one.

You can see this work by running something like

```
(map (fn [i x]
       (println i x))
     (range) ; The first collection
     ["A" "B" "C"]) ; The second collection

0 A
1 B
2 C
=> (nil nil nil)
```

That above example can also be simply written as

```
(map println (range) ["A" "B" "C"])
```

The number of collections given to `map` decides how many arguments need to be given to the mapping function. Since I gave two collections to `map` here, the mapping function needs to take two parameters; `i` and `x` in this case.

In your example, `map` is also taking two collections, `A` and `B`. Since `=` takes any number of arguments, it can be used here to check that each element in one collection is the same as the element at the same index in another collection.

Or, in other words

```
(mapv = [1 2 3] [1 2 4])
```

Is basically the same thing as

```
[(= 1 1)
 (= 2 2)
 (= 3 4)] ; Note that they differ here
```

Which returns `[true true false]`. The last being false because the last elements of each collection don't match.

It's a pairwise equality check of two collections.

Comment: Ok, it is very clear to me now. Can you explain on the same way (reduce #(and %1 %2)) ?

Comment: @nenad For that, I'd just play around with `reduce`, as there isn't much in the way of fancy stuff going on there. I will say though that that could/should be written as `(every? identity` instead. Both just check if every element in a collection is truthy. In this case, it's checking that every value returned by the `map` is truthy.

Comment: @nenad Also, I answered this because I thought I could write a good answer, but really, this question, and a couple recent questions by you, are quite broad. Please try to narrow down what you're asking to make more specific questions. The entire functionality of reduce and map aren't very specific, and could be answered by just getting some practice with both.

Comment: When we get a sequence from (map = A B), does the (reduce #(and %1 %2)...) takes every time two new arguments or? That part I can't figure out.

Comment: @nenad I'm not sure what you mean. The map returns a list of boolean values as I showed above.

Comment: Yes, I know [true false true true...], and than #(and %1 %2) takes the first two of them from list and returns first false value because "and" function does that right? Or last, if there is no falsey.

Comment: @nenad No, it takes one element at a time. `%1` is whatever `and` last returned. It's the accumulator of the fold/reduction. It maintains if every element is true, since as soon as an element is false, the accumulator will become false, and every check with `and` after that will becomes false. Stick a `println` in there to see what's going on.

Comment: Now I am totaly confused. Can you just tell me what is %1 argument and what %2. What we take exactly from result  (true false true true...)?

Comment: @nenad Again, `%1` is whatever `and` returned on the last iteration. `%2` will become each element of the collection, just like with `map`. Reducing over `[true false true]`, `%1` will start as true, then you have `(and true true)`, the second true is `%2`, the first element of the collection. Because `and` returns true in this case, on the next iteration `%1` will be true again. Then because the second element of the collection is false, it'll check `(and true false)`. That will return false, so `%1` will be false on the next iteration. Then it'll check `(and false true)`, which is also false

Comment: @nenad As an alternative example that should clear things up, see here: https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/9b33a4d567378081c70e9ef7792452a6.

Comment: I think that reducing over [true false true], %1 will start as true and %2 will start as false, beacuse we are applying function to the first two elements in collection. Than (and true false) will return false and than in next iteration we will have (and false true) right?

Comment: @nenad Yes, I said basically that in my second last comment. Also, the exam in the link is much clearer than the problem you're facing in your question. I'd learn the code in the link, then apply that to your problem.